# get search box from google maps on my site with google maps api

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-places-api

I like google maps. There's smart search box. I want to have it on my own website with google maps api.

I have some experience with google maps places library - autocomplete, place searches and places search box - but it seems google maps website itself uses more complex search box that is offered by it's api.

Let's consider several search queries at maps.google.com and https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-searchbox pages:

- type "moscow" and press enter (do not choose anything in the autocomplete box) - google maps works works fine, but search box api returns two objects (one in russia and another one in usa).
- type "moscow" and choose first result from autocomplete - search box again returns two results - one for moscow, and another one for moskva small village.
- type "camping" - google maps itself works excellent - it shows campings for the current map position and updates it while the map is dragged and zoomed. Search box doesn't update results. There's code with searchBox.setBounds for bounds_changed, but it does not trigger places_changed event, and markers don't update on the map.

These examples show that google maps itself uses more powerful version of the search box, that is offered in api. So is it possible to have this more powerful search box on my website?

Comment: Let's assume that maps.google.com didn't use the API at all. When you want another behaviour for the searchbox you must implement it(it's possible) on your own. The demo-page shows only a possible implementation(e.g. it creates marker for all results).  When you need only 1 marker create only a marker for the first result.

Comment: API is the only legal way to use google maps on my website. If google maps itself uses API (there might be a lot of code around, but the core search box is from API) - I can write something similar. If google maps uses something different - I can't do anything.